# Python - Package in another workspace gets called?

Tags: python

I am using Spyder (if this matters) for my Python project.

I have two workspaces
`...\projects\proj1` and `...\projects\proj2`. In both `proj1` and `proj2`, I have a package named `dr`.

However, the `dr` in `proj1` has **4 modules** named `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`, whereas the `dr` in `proj2` has **2 modules** named `A` and `B` (same names as `proj1`).

Currently, I am in workspace `...\projects\proj2`. When I import the `dr` package and try to call the `A` module,

```
from dr import A
A.
```

All the function suggestions that follow the `A.` are the functions from `proj1`, but I am now in `...\projects\proj2` workspace!

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: It must be a path issue. I doubt Spyder has issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved by renaming the packages so as to make it different from the one in another project. I think this is a bug in Spyder. Please correct me if I am wrong.